# Finding the Average Power Loss in a Series RL Circuit

Tags: power, impedance

**Question :**

> A current \$I=3\sin(400t)\$ amperes in a series RL circuit in which
>   \$L=1mH\$ and \$R=100Ω\$. What is the average power loss?

**Answer :**

$$ APL = 450 \space W $$

---

**My Steps :**
\begin{align}
P&=IV\\
 &=I(IZ)\\
 &=I^2Z\\
 &=I^2(jwL+R)\\
 &=I^2[j(400)(0.001)+100]\\
 &=(3\angle0)^2[j(400)(0.001)+100]\\
 &=[9\angle(0+0)][100+j0.4]\\
 &=[9\angle0](100\angle0.229)\\
 &=(9\times100)\angle(0+0.229)\\
 &=900\angle0.229\space W\\
\end{align}

So the APL should be 900W. What is wrong with my idea?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the peak value of current in your solution.

The RMS value of current is of course \$\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{2}}\$ = 2.121 amps and this flows thru the 100 ohm resistor producing a power of

\$(\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{2}})^2\times 100\$ = 450 watts.

Remember the current is flowing through the resistor so you don't need to care about it also flowing thru the inductor and your angle of 0.229 is meaningless and also incorrect due to rounding errors.

Answer (score 1):

There is no power loss in an ideal inductor as it just stores then releases energy.

The power loss is therefore \$I^2 \cdot R\$ where \$ I \$ is the rms current giving 450 watt as answered by Andy.

Another approach if you want to use the total voltage across the circuit is to note

\$ Z = j \omega L + R = j \cdot 400 \cdot 0.001 + 100 = 100 + 0.4 \cdot j = 100.001 \angle \ 0.229^o\$

Now taking the rms current we get \$ I = \cfrac{3}{\sqrt{2}} = 2.1213\$ amp,

\$V_{rms} = I_{rms} \cdot Z = 212.13415 \angle \ 0.229^o\$

\$P = V_{rms} \cdot I_{rms} \cdot \cos \theta = 212.13415 \cdot 2.1213 \cos (0.229^o) = 449.997\$

Which is the same answer Andy gave, or would be if this one did not have rounding errors.